# scp error while doing scp from host to target

Tags: linux, scp

While doing scp from host PC(ubuntu-12.04) to target board(IMX6), it is giving following error:

```
#scp Test.txt root@10.20.119.101:/home/root
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Test.txt                                                                 100% 8599     8.4KB/s   00:00    
#
```

Can you guide to fix this issue.

Comment: You have probably changed the default shell for the `root` user. Never do that. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/is-it-bad-practice-to-set-roots-shell-to-something-other-than-the-default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [these](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=249039.0) [texts](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/13852) (I googled the error), this happens if the super-user account has its default shell changed to `bash`.

Never do that. It is bad practice to change the default shell for the `root` user.

See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.admin/Ip2XQESt8ME) on the `comp.unix.admin` USENET forum.

Comment: I haven't changed default shell for root in /etc/passwd file . I have changed the soft link of /bin/sh to /bin/ash instead of /bin/bash under /bin directory. So now all references to /bin/sh will point to /bin/ash.

Comment: @Ravi That's even *worse*. That means that not only the login shell is different but *all system scripts* will now be executed with `ash` instead of `bash` (in `sh` mode).  For that to be a valid thing to do, one has to perform an audit of *all* system scripts installed on the machine to make sure they do not trigger behaviour that comes from differences in the way `ash` does things.

Comment: @Ravi Just put the system defaults back to whatever they were.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I reverted the changes and created new user on the target with default shell as "ash" using "adduser" command. Now I am using newly created user for scp and is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ash instead of bash then the error was not observed.

Existing:
/bin/sh -> /bin/bash

Modified:
/bin/sh -> /bin/ash